# css locator that would shortens multiple td's

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors

SeleniumIDE in firefox, using a locator of

```
css=table#students tr +tr td +td +td +td +td +td +td +td
mytext
```

for the last column in thr row of a table.
Any shorter way to do this with a css locator ?

before I switch to xpath, which is something like

```
//table//tr//td[contains(@text,'mytext')]
```

or

```
//table//tr//td[8][text='mytext']
```

Comment: just a small correction on your last XPath, I think it should be `//table//tr//td[8][text()='mytext']`

Comment: And if you must select the `td` containing that text, you cannot do it with a CSS locator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the last column, try [last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type) (I haven't tested it on Selenium-IDE, but works for WebDriver)

```
table#students tr + tr > td:last-of-type
```

If you just want to index the one of the td, use nth-of-type

```
table#students tr + tr > td:nth-of-type(8)
```

If you have to use text to find it, then this can't be done using Css Selector, unless you use [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/).

```
table#students tr + tr > td:contains(mytext)
```

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: oh well, you mean the locator doesn't work or it doesn't work on Selenium IDE? Also this matches the css locator you provided, not with the xpath you used. As BoltClock said, css doesn't support locating text, unless you use sizzle.